# Change view using ajax on drop-down list change event

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc, viewbag

I need to change the view in same page using ajax when the user changes the option of the drop-down list.

Up until now in my view I have the drop down list

```
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div>
            <label>Get cars per people </label>
            @Html.DropDownList("ddlChange", new SelectList(ViewBag.OptionsList,"Value","Text", ViewBag.selectedValue),new { @id = "ddlChangeID" })
        </div>
        <div class="box box-success">
            <div class="box-body">
                <div>
                    <canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Then in a script (which I found from another question)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#ddlChangeID").change(function () {
        var strSelected = "";
        $("#ddlChangeID:selected").each(function () {
            strSelected += $(this)[0].value;
        });
        var url = "/Cars/Index/" + strSelected;
        $.post(url, function (data) {
        });
    });
})
```

And in the controller I am using ViewBag values to save the drop-down list values and whatever else is needed for the graph which loads in a different script again with ViewBag values. I have managed to pass the selected value (strSelected) but the view does not reload with the new data.

How should I make the ajax event?

Answer (score 1):

Change your script ajax call by calling an action result as follows

```
$("#ddlChangeID").change(function () {
  $.ajax({
    url: "/Controller/ActionHtml?id="+$('#ddlChange').val(),
  type: "POST",
  cache: false,
  success: function (result) {
     $("#myChart").html(result);
    },
    error: function () {
       $("#myChart").empty();
    }
 });
});
```

and in the controller the actionresult will be like the following which returns the html partial view that you need to append

```
 public ActionResult ActionHtml(string id)
    {
       //Here you can load the data based on the id,pass model to the patial views etc
        ViewBag.id = id;
        return PartialView("~/Views/Shared/myhtml.cshtml");
    }
```

`myhtml.cshtml` will be a partial view with the html content as 
         //content is dummy,change the content as you want

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<p>Enter some text in the fields below, then press the "Reset form" button to reset the form.</p>
<form id="myForm">
    First name: <input type="text" name="fname"><br>
    Last name: <input type="text" name="lname"><br><br>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

So I changed the

```
     @Html.DropDownList("ddlChange", new SelectList(ViewBag.OptionsList,"Value","Text", ViewBag.selectedValue),new { @id = "ddlChangeID" })
```

To

```
     @Html.DropDownList("ddlChange", new SelectList(ViewBag.OptionsList,"Value","Text", ViewBag.selectedValue),new { @onchange = "ChangeOption()" })
```

adding also an id to the main div.
And the script to

```
function ChangeOption() {
    var id = $('#ddlChange').val();
    $.ajax({
        url: '/Cars/Index',
        type: "GET",
        data: { Id: id },
        success: function (data) {
            $('#wrapAll').html(data);
        }
    });
}
```

It seems to work. Only issue now is that the css breaks.
It pushes the graph and drop-down list to the right breaking 
the functionality.